# Need to send messages via Node JS Websocket from user to user with json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, websocket

I want to establish a websocket controlserver for my unity application. A HTML client should send a JSON Code including target and commando. The server should parse for the target and commando and should send it to the specific client and vice versa.

My problem is: I am not able combine the connection with the client... something like connection[user] and adress this with the username included in the json message. There are not many useful examples on the internet for this case. Especially for the right syntax

Hopefully someone can help me out :-)

```
//===============================================
// Websocket Command Server 1.0
//===============================================

// Websocket-Server
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({host: 'localhost',port: 1337});

console.log('Server gestartet...');

wss.on('connection', function(ws) 
{

    var userName = false;

    console.log('client verbunden...');

    ws.on('message', function(message) 
    {
        if (userName === false) { // first message sent by user is their name

            // remember user name
            userName = message;
            console.log((new Date()) + ' Received Message from ' + userName + ': ' + message);
        }

        else { // log and broadcast the message

                    var obj = JSON.parse(message);
                     if("User" in obj) {
                        // New client, add it to the id/client object           
                        var targetuser = obj.user; 
                        console.log('targetuser: ' + obj.user);
                    }

                     if ("Command" in obj){
                        // Send data to the client requested
                        var command = obj.command;
                        console.log('Command: ' + obj.command);
                      }
                      else {
                        console.log('nix im json');
                      }
                    targetuser.send(command);


        }});
 });
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/367 to see how to keep track of connected users so that you can send data to any user. It's fairly simple.

Comment: Why not take a look at something like http://crossbar.io, which adds messaging patterns on top of WebSocket? (I'm affiliated with the project, but there are other projects out there which add comfort on top of WebSocket)

Comment: Crossbar.io seems to complicated for my purpose. ;-). I can keep track of my users with counting. But how can I apply usernames and adress them? Because I don't know who connects first?